# Using Mobx decorators breaks react storybook

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react, storybook

I am trying to combine React Storybook and MobX decoratos options.

I have this type of component

```
@inject("RootStore")
@observer
class Second extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Helmet>
          <title>Second route</title>
          <meta name="description" content="Second stranica" />
        </Helmet>

        <Link to="/">First route</Link>
        <button type="button">{this.props.RootStore.text}</button>

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Second;
```

React storybook starts working as soon as I remove

```
@inject("RootStore")
@observer
```

This is my config

```
storiesOf("Second", module)
  .addDecorator(story => (
    <MemoryRouter initialEntries={["/"]}>{story()}</MemoryRouter>
  ))

  .add("normal", () => <Second />);
```

babel.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ["@babel/preset-react", "@babel/preset-env"],
  plugins: [
    [
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators",
      {
        legacy: true
      }
    ],
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", { loose: true }]
  ]
};
```

I get the error that I have no stories available. No preview.

How do I fix it?